# Where to put ViewModel classes in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model, viewmodel

My question is very simple. I want to know where to put my `ViewModels` in an MVC application.

Currently the project I'm working on only has `ViewModels` and they are stored in the `Models` folder. In that folder we directly create ViewModel classes.

But normally I would also have `Model` classes, to get data from a database or something. Then from a `Controller` I'd 'talk' to a Model method and store the result in a `ViewModel` property.

But where do I put the `Model` classes and `ViewModel` classes when I use both of them? What is a good practice in the sense of structuring my files/folders for these two?

Comment: I see no problem in having a `ViewModel` folder. There are no constraints which state that the `Model` folder should be present.

Comment: @AndreiV I know, but I have both now. So is it 'normal' to put a  `ViewModel` in a ViewModels folder and a `Model` in a Models folder?

Comment: I would go with `ViewModel` as a sub folder `Model`, if you're using both to display data in the views. If not, separate folders would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just create a new folder called ViewModels inside your project. So that along with the Views, Controllers and Models folders, you'll also have ViewModels. 
Like you already said, you talk to your DAL using your models and you talk to your views using your view models.

Answer (score 3):

You need to structure your files and folders in a way that you and the people that follow you will find intuitive and maintainable.

I don't think there is any hard and fast rules about folder structure, just some are a lot worse than others. If it seems illogical and a bit smelly, then it probably is.

What you're proposing seems fine

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate folder"ViewModels" and refer the namespace in controller and refer the same in the respective view